# How to handle truncated or missing ranking data in a classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, references, missing-data, truncation

I'm preparing data for a classification problem that involves matches in a single-player sport. In each match, each competitor is either ranked and thus has a numeric rank; or unranked (rare but can happen) or has his rank info missing. I would like to include the rank as a feature to predict the outcome of the match.

> What are the recommended approaches in dealing with unranked players or players with rank info missing? And is there a name please for this kind of situation?

I have a few options:

1. Limit the time periods to portions of the data with no issue above.
2. Delete matches with the issue
3. Give the unranked player or the player without rank a really low rank
4. Include a dummy for a player when his rank info is unavailable.

Option 1 makes the most sense to me but it is also the most wasteful. Either way, I would like to learn established solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If more information is available, you may wish to incorporate it into assigning a missing data point.

For example, a study of players historical rankings over time, including those who were unranked for a period, might suggest a more meaningful value (derived from their average rank) than using just a team average value.

Losing data is not usually the best option and adding dummy variables could decrease the accuracy of all estimates.

There is also the problem of explaining your choice. Now, a select data record for assigning the missing value could be challenged, but only by those with more knowledge, which could be incorporated into a revised study.